# How to get UICollectionViewCell SuperView as UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to get indexPath of a UICollectionViewCell inside CollectionViewCell class. I have created an extension for this, but it returning nil

I tried this code

```swift
extension UICollectionViewCell{

    var collectionView:UICollectionView?{
        return superview as? UICollectionView
    }

    var indexPath:IndexPath?{
        return collectionView?.indexPath(for: self)
    }
}
```

It is returning nil for `superview as? UICollectionView`

Comment: Why do you need the indexpath in CollectionViewCell class?

Comment: I am trying to get cell size set in 
```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
}
```

Comment: Why does your cell need to access the size from there? The cell will have its size updated and you can do what you need as the size changes.

Comment: If you feel the need to get the collection view or the index path from the cell then you are doing something fundamentally wrong. There are proper solutions depending on what you really are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @rmaddy Actually I am trying to create a chat Like UI containing text and Image Messages. Image cell size being Constant, but text cell size according to text length and maximum width allowed for text bubble. I want to avoid double call of same function to calculate text bubble size in `sizeForItemAt` and in Cell class.

Comment: Why do you have to calculate the size in the cell class? Base things on the size of the cell.

Comment: @rmaddy suppose I calculate text bubble size with a text message "Hello World". Let it gives a size with width: 70 and height: 34. I set the cell size in `sizeForItemAt` for this. If there is another message with "Hello", collection view will show these two messages in one line where as I want message in separate lines. So I set cell size width as collection view bounds width. But when setting cell views like textview I have to re calculate size of text view again. So Double calculation for same process which I want to avoid.

Comment: Why avoid it? Don't worry about it unless you actually have a measurable performance issue.

Comment: Ok thanks for helping. Will find any alternate solution if there are performance issues.